# How do I handle a simple polymorphic association in my views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, single-table-inheritance

I've got some models that look like this:

```
class Basket
  has_many :fruits, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Fruit
  belongs_to :basket  # do I need a polymorphic association here?
end

class Apple < Fruit
  validate :crunchy
end

class Banana < Fruit
  validate :peelable
end
```

Fruit is abstract in the sense that you never create, update, etc., Fruits, but rather Apples or Bananas. That means that I can't write something like `edit_fruit_path(@fruit)` in my views and have it automatically resolve.

What should I write in my views so that it always resolves to `edit_apple_path(@fruit)` or `edit_banana_path(@fruit)`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a polymorphic but rather a Single Table Inheritance.

I am assuming that you will inherit ActiveRecord::Base to Fruit.

Add the column `type` to your fruits table.

Now you can do `edit_fruit_path(@apple)` and it will be the Apple object.